# Bypass / Defer AngularJS $http.get Promise

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am using ngTagsInput to handle my tags in my AngularJS project. It has an auto-complete directive. To handle the data going into the directive it assumes that you are going to do:

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $http.get('tags.json');
  };
```

Which returns a promise. Here comes the tricky part I want to do the same thing this is doing but I already have an object in my $scope that has all the tags I want to use for auto-completing. I can't simply do $scope.loadTags because this returns an error.

> Cannot Read Property 'then' of Undefined.

How do I bypass this promise or defer it?

This is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/wEqVMf?p=preview

Directive:
    app.directive('tag', function($http) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'tag.html',
        link: function (scope, el) {
           scope.tags = [
              { text: 'Tag1' },
              { text: 'Tag2' },
              { text: 'Tag3' }
            ];

```
        var test = [{ text: 'Tag9' },{ text: 'Tag10' }];

        scope.loadTags = test;
    }
  }
});
```

Html which is inside of `<tag>`

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags">
  <auto-complete ng-model="loadTags"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
<p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$q.when()` to create a resolved promise from the array...

```
scope.loadTags = function () {
    var test = [{ text: 'Tag9' },{ text: 'Tag10' }];
    return $q.when(test); 
};
```

There is also one addition error in the `tag.html` template. `ng-model="loadTags"` should be `source="loadTags(query)"`...

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags">
    <auto-complete source="loadTags(query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/fEO3MVInVe7TnFkHyCNq?p=preview